# jQuery / JS adding onClick button value into row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am really new with JavaScript so i have been looking to make something with it. However i wanted to make that when you press X button it will print that button value into a div. The think how i want is that if you press one button and value is 1, it will print 1 to div and if you press 2nd button that value is 2 it will print 2 after the 1. So like 12 and not 3 (like in my JSFiddle down below)

I hope i can get help from here.

Here is my JSFiddle

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLo7ah1m/)

```js
var theTotal = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
   theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
    $('.total').text(" "+theTotal);        
});
```

```css
#codebar {
  background:black;
  width:150px;
  height:20px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.total {
  color: red;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:50px;
  margin-top:-18px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="1">1</button>
<button value="2">2</button>
<button value="3">3</button>
<button value="4">4</button>
<button value="5">5</button>
<button value="6">6</button>
<button value="7">7</button>
<button value="8">8</button>
<button value="9">9</button>
<button value="10">10</button>

<br>

<div id="codebar">
<div class="total"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So do not convert them to numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `.append()` the button `value` as *string*

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.total').append($(this).val());        
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cLo7ah1m/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! New issue is that how to set that you can only set max 3 numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the number Conversion:

```
var theTotal = 0;

$('button').click(function(){
   theTotal = theTotal + $(this).val();
   $('.total').text(" "+theTotal);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you had been close to the target.You can try this.

```js
var theTotal = '';
$('button').click(function(){
  theTotal = theTotal + " " + $(this).val();
  $('.total').text(theTotal);        
});
```

I just make a simple change with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use .append() or concat  instead of sum...but one more best practice is using data attributes instead of button value.

```js
var theTotal = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).data('value');
  $('.total').append(value);
});
```

```css
#codebar {
  background: black;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.total {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button value="1" data-value="1">1</button>
<button value="2" data-value="2">2</button>
<button value="3" data-value="3">3</button>
<button value="4" data-value="4">4</button>

<div id="codebar">
  <div class="total"></div>
</div>
```

If we take your code mistake is..

```js
var theTotal = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
   theTotal = Number(theTotal) +''+ Number($(this).val());
    $('.total').text(" "+theTotal);        
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try It Once

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var a = 0; 
  $('button').click(function(){
   
 $(this).each(function(){
  a += $(this).text();
   
   $('.total').html(a);
 });
  });
});
```

```css
 

#codebar {
  background:black;
  width:150px;
  height:20px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.total {
  color: red;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:50px;
  margin-top:-18px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="1">1</button>
<button value="2">2</button>
<button value="3">3</button>
<button value="4">4</button>
<button value="5">5</button>
<button value="6">6</button>
<button value="7">7</button>
<button value="8">8</button>
<button value="9">9</button>
<button value="10">10</button>




<div id="codebar">
<div class="total"></div>
</div>
```